# Select MAX date between 4 columns using Hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

it´s possible to make this criteria?

```
SELECT MAX(DATA_VER) FROM(VALUES (MED.DAT_VERIFICACAO_CANAL1), (MED.DAT_VERIFICACAO_CANAL2),(MED.DAT_VERIFICACAO_CANAL3),(MED.DAT_VERIFICACAO_CANAL4)) AS MAX_VALUE(DATA_VER)) <= '04-04-2019 02:28:00';
```

Theses columns are in the same table.